# PDE - Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

What physics phenomenom does the Laplace equation describes?
From what I know of, its the static problems but what it actually means?

Comment: You've made an effort to find out, right?

Comment: Start with Wikipedia, maybe?